# How to use spark dataframe api to calculate quantile with groupBy?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I have some data like this:

```
id  country  salary
1     US      2000
2     US      3500
3     US      2600
4     JPN     2500
5     JPN     3800
6     CHN     2400
7     CHN     3200
```

I want to group by "country" then calculate the 75,95,99 quantile of salary
How could I do?
Is there a method like calculate mean,sum similar to

```
df.groupBy("country").agg(sum($"salary"))
and 
df.groupBy("country").agg(quantileFunction)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I have done to calculate quantiles for Candlestick chart/Box & whisker plot, a percentile function. In your case this might work:

```
df.registerTempTable("table1")
df2 = sqlContext.sql("Select id, 
                             country, 
                             percentile(salary, 75) as 75quant,
                             percentile(salary, 95) as 95quant,
                             percentile(salary, 99) as 99quant
                     from table1
                     group by country")
```

Comment: Can I use percentile in dataframe api, like df.groupBy("country").agg(percentile)?